# MongoDB Lookup performance

Tags: mongodb, performance, aggregation-framework

I wanted to know if there is a difference between this piece of code:

```
    return await _post
        .aggregate([
            {
                $match: filters
            },
            {
                $addFields: {
                    totalLikes: { "$size": "$likes" },
                    totalComments: { "$size": "$comments" },
                }
            },
            {
                $sort: sort
            },
            {
                $skip: skips
            },
            {
                $limit: pageSize
            },
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: _comment.collection.name,
                    localField: 'comments',
                    foreignField: '_id',
                    as: 'comments',
                },
            },

        ])
};
```

And this

```
   return await _post
        .aggregate([
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: _comment.collection.name,
                    localField: 'comments',
                    foreignField: '_id',
                    as: 'comments',
                },
            },
            {
                $addFields: {
                    totalLikes: { "$size": "$likes" },
                    totalComments: { "$size": "$comments" },
                }
            },
            {
                $match: filters
            },
            {
                $sort: sort
            },
            {
                $skip: skips
            },
            {
                $limit: pageSize
            },
        ])
};
```

My question is basically, the lookup is always done over all documents, or if I apply filters first, it is applied over the filtered ones only?.
There is another way to improve performance?
Thanks!

Comment: The second one should be faster, because you lookup **every** value, even those which are not used later. Maybe the smarter design would be to put the comments as array subdocument in the main collection. NoSQL databases like MongoDB don't have their focus on joins which you use frequently on relational databases.

Comment: So, the lookup is not being done over the result of documents after the match?. Even if I add it after the match, it is looking up all the documents.? 
Regarding the array of subdocuments, I have in mind to re structure the schema and use some pattern that helps me in case an array grows too much

Comment: The output of a pipeline stage is the input for the next stage in the pipeline. So, you should use $match, $limit, $skip as early as possible. Obviously I made a typo in my comment above.